# Implementing SwingWorker

Tags: java, performance, swing, swingworker

Thought of making a small textEditor.  It will contain two textareas, one for entering the text and one for error display. As for my understanding, SwingWorker works in background so there will be no delay in the UI updation.  For checking, i wrote the below code and inserted 5000 lines and tried to type, i think as the line goes on increasing, the updation in textEditor2 is becoming very slow.  Is the implementation of the swingworker is correct in the code?

textEditor1 and textEditor2 are JTextarea

```
 private void editorKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    String text = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        text = textEditor1.getText().toString();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            get();
            textEditor2.setText(text);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
};

worker.execute();   
}
```

Comment: get() catches exceptions thrown by doInBackground()

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question and indicate what you try to achieve (from a user point of view), and then we can suggest a decent solution. Since something as simple as validation of user input typically does not require a Swingworker, unless your validation takes several seconds. But then you would not be able to perform validation on every keystroke since your average user types a lot faster then that

Comment: This is a very bad example. For one you're making Swing calls from a background thread (`getText()`). Throw this example out.

Comment: @shiva0101 m please from where you take this example for get(), I have to kill this page on the some of ExampleDepots

Comment: @mKorbel, do whatever you like, https://wiki.palantir.com/pgdz/using-a-swing-worker.html

Comment: @shiva0101 m ahaaaaaa but this code depots contains correct describtions and code examples too :-), sorry this is miss_interpretations by yourself :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, miss_interpretations! where?

Comment: try ---> get() ---> catch..., should be empty statement without intection to the GUI (textEditor2.setText(text);), I read your question and answers here, please try to explain that more, because you really don't needed any KeyListener not dealyed with SwingWorker, this is job for DocumentListener and if you really needed something as animations then use Thread.sleep(int) in SwingWorker or use Swing Timer

Comment: @mKorbel, i take the contents of the text process/validate/add color and update the editor  I have to do it frequently, say every half   a minute or so, John, pointed out, that spawing worker thread every time the key is pressed is causing the problem. Iam calling the swingworker periodically.  It seems ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are spawning worker threads every time the key is pressed, I expect that's why you're seeing the degradation in performance.

You still need to manage the number of threads you're executing to maintain UI responsiveness.  If you want your background task to always be running, setup your own thread and use a class from the concurrent package to fascilitate passing data off of the Event thread (e.g. [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)).

Comment: Yes, but this listener should work every time, when text is changed.

Comment: Believe that's the problem... on every key press a new swingworker is instantiated and executed (i.e. it is working).  The context switching to each new thread (if they're being spawned quickly) is slowing everything down.

Comment: Yeah, john.  now i am calling swingworker periodically.   It seems it's fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this task you should not use SwingWorker. Just do It in one thread.

```
private void editorKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
text = textEditor1.getText();
textEditor2.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Balconsky, yeah, i know that text = textEditor1.getText();
textEditor2.setText(text); can be done.  I am thinking of writing validtion code in doInBackground() and updation in done(), I thought swingworker will run in background and there will be no down performance, but as the line gets longer the texteditors are almost freezing.

Comment: What listener do you use? Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html

Comment: I have not implemented documentListener, should i have to?